# Need help to fix an issue aroused due to 2 javascript objects having same name but different constructors

Tags: javascript, forms

We have an application where we have multiple forms & each form has submit button (ofcourse). The way we have made it work is have common submit button which has an event bound on click of that button to call formSubmit method on an object with name commonObject.
Now, each javascript creates object with same name commonObject & the formSubmit method gets called on each page perfectly fine.
Complication arises when we have linked use cases & lets say due to business logic, when customer submits formA, we need to redirect them to formB & upon submission of formB, we need to take them back to formA. It can easily create loop, but that's what Business logic needs us to do.

Behavior in such cases become very unpredictable & Javascript invokes formSubmit on formA or formB. How do we ensure that it calls formSubmit only on the form that was loaded last?

Comment: you need to post some code

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution here in case anyone else ends up having same problem.

Let me first narrate the scenario by some code as requested in comment first.
Old code, which created problem -

```
FormAPage.js
function formAPage() {
   this.submitForm = submitForm;
}
var commonObject = new formAPage();

function submitForm() {
   //ajax call to submit the form A
}


FormBPage.js
function formBPage() {
   this.submitForm = submitForm;
}
var commonObject = new formBPage();

function submitForm() {
   //ajax call to submit the form B
}
```

Now, imagine the scenario where we submit form A & business logic dictated application to load form B. Result is there are 2 objects created with name of commonObject & both has similar prototype, how would JS would know which object script to execute. So, we ended up having a problem of JS trying to submit form A again even after load of form B.
The way we resolved it is by using different prototypes/constructor's for each object.

We updated the actual function name to submitFormA & submitFormB, but in constructor we call it this.submitForm = submitFormA.
This changes the constructor definition's of commonObject created the first time & second time & they no longer conflict with each other.

Updated code to fix the issue -
    FormAPage.js
    function formAPage() {
       this.submitForm = submitFormA;
    }
    var commonObject = new formAPage();

```
function submitFormA() {
   //ajax call to submit the form A
}


FormBPage.js
function formBPage() {
   this.submitForm = submitFormB;
}
var commonObject = new formBPage();

function submitFormB() {
   //ajax call to submit the form B
}
```